# How to copy the content from one cell to another

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am try to check if any column1, any of the cell's is not empty. i want to make then empty and copy the file to next column-cell. What ,my idea is to check if one particular Column1- all cells lets say "COLUMN1" one of the cell is not empty. Then i need the file [ I have attached the file path to that particular cell] to get copied to next column2. at the same time i want to copy the file to a folder on my desktop Lets say the location is C:/user/elec/copy, and i want to erase the Column1 -cell data.

How can i do this. Link for what i am trying to do..

[image]

**Edited coding.....**

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string copyPath = @"C:\user\elec\copy";
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(copyPath))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(copyPath);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    string filePath = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                        string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(copyPath, fileName);
                        System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, newpath, true);
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = newpath;

                        try
                        {
                            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SREEJITHMOHA492\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
                            {
                                con.Open();
                                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                                cmd.CommandText = "update cncinfo set draftpath=@draftpath,releasepath=@releasepath Where part=@part";
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@draftpath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = filePath;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@releasepath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newpath;
                                cmd.CommandText = "update cncinfo set draftpath='" + string.Empty + "',releasepath=@releasepath Where part=@part";
                                //you must have the id value in datagridview to update the specific record.
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@part", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Part Number"].Value);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                con.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = string.Empty;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: So, what's your actual problem?

Comment: @JohnSaunders i dont know how to do this.. please help me out.. i want to copy a cell content to another column cell content.. how to do this..

Comment: Do some research. Don't just Google for examples. Go learn the DataGridView class. Question: what's the data type of the cells of the `DataGridView`? Does it have any properties or methods that have anything to do with the clipboard?

Comment: @Shell howzz going ... can you help me with this issue.. pleaseee

Comment: @Shell also i want to updated the new locations and data to database too. please help me out.. So that i can close this entire topic.. Thanks a lot Shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of problems in your code. you are trying to read `DataGridViewCell` instead of its value. to read the cell value you must have to return value from `.Value` property of `DataGridVIewCell`. ie. `string x=dgv.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value`. Row does not contains Columns it contains Cells. So, to read the value from particular cell you should read that value from Cell object instead of Column.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string copyPath = @"C:\user\elec\copy";
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(copyPath))
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(copyPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null && 
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
        {
            string filePath = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {                   
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(copyPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, newpath, true);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = newpath;

                try
                { 
                    Using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=STACY121\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True"))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "update cncinfo set Column1=@Column1,Column2=@Column2 Where id=@id";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column1",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =filePath;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column2",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =newpath;
                        //you must have the id value in datagridview to update the specific record.
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id",SqlDbType.Int).Value =Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value);


                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                 }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                } 
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**

if you would like to copy with different file name then you can specify the file name like this.

```
int iFileNo = 1; // this is the part of file number in sample-rev-01
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
string ext = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath).Extension;
//if the file name is sample.txt then it would be return as sample-rev-01.txt
fileName = String.Format("{0}-rev-{1:00}{2}", fileName.Replace(ext, ""), iFileNo, ext);

string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(copyPath, fileName);
System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, newpath, true);
```

Comment: i have error for Exist, create, Cell.. thenn line `string filePath = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;` and in last line rows too.. `dataGridView1.row.Cells[0].Value = string.Empty;`

Comment: that was a perfect one. but its not updating in my database. When i close my application, and re-openend it, its the same like initially.. i am using sql server

Comment: You haven't mentioned that you want to update that records in database. You need to create another function to save that records in database. BTW, how do you fill the records in the grid? add that code also in you question.

Comment: can i have ur mail address.. please

Comment: i have a problem here.. i have given the code for updation.. stil it not working i have updated the codes please have a look

Comment: The copied files to the column2 is not showing me the new path. i mean i need to show there the new path.. that is..from `@"C:\user\elec\copy";`

Comment: I have some doubts. In your code you are trying to update record from `column1path`(textbox) instead of grid cell. and in which column of your datagridview, you are storing the id of that record?

Comment: @Stacy i have updated code to update that record in database.

Comment: its showing me each time a dialog box called column name @id cannot be found.. and when i re-open my app its showing me the same... May be my column name is id.. and i have updated the id to `Part Number`.. is it because of that

Comment: Ok i got it.. its perfect.. now.. but when i re-open the winform.. the coulmn1 is not deleted... rest every thing is good.. its copying. to column2 and new location is also coming.. but the column1 is not deleted from database

Comment: I mean column1 values are not deleted.. LOL..:P. updated in database

Comment: I have updated my answer @Stacy please take a look. If you have more question about it you can find me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net-with-c-vb-mvc

Comment: geting an error in `fileName = String.Format("{0}-rev-{1:00}{2}", fileName.Replace(ext, ""), iFileNo, ext);
` . The error is An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String cannot be of zero length.

Comment: I gave the entire in a new button. Is that u coded.. or... i would like to update under same button.. Because it should check for coulumn two contains attachement.. if attachment is there in column2 and i am again moving a new file from column1 then the column2 file move to new location and column1 file comes to the column2 location. Can u merge two fucntion under same button and send me.. I have updated the entire codess...as you said please have a lokk.

Comment: i check you code the both file is coming in the same location..:-(old file is not moving to new location.

Comment: the `System.IO.File.Copy()` method will copy the file only to new location. but, if you want to move the file to its new location and it should not be available on old file location then you can use `System.IO.File.Move()` method ie. `System.IO.File.Move(filePath, newpath);` and I have checked your code it was working fine for me. i will give u a sample project that works correctly

Comment: I have checked that code in my sample project. Download the form from [here](http://www.dantainfosoft.a78.org/SampleForm.rar) and include in your test project and try again. It should work like this.

Comment: that is working but the old file in the Column2 is not moving to a different folder/// lets say :@"D:/Temp"..  i want the old files in the `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value ` i want that file to move to a diferent location.
And the new file in `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value` want to move `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value `. So this process should be repetitive.

Comment: So the condition is like this 

`if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value !=null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()))
                                                   {
                               // Here goees your codes.. this is the iniitial condition..
}

if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value !=null && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value !=null)
{
 // here when a new file is added to the cell[2] that is the rev of file1 which is in cell[3]. So i need to move the file in cell[3] to a different folder
//and file in cell[2] to the cell[3].
}`