# My variable is not getting incremented

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, auto-increment

I have a winform application. When i try to increment a textbox value with **+5** its not getting incremented. There is something I am missing can you guys help me.
i am using WriteLine() function to write all to a text box. Please help me its a simple thing I am missing to add after my X character

I am getting the output as

N1 G02 X22.020 Y16.24

N2 G02 X22.025 Y16.24

N3 G02 X22.0210 Y16.24

N4 G02 X22.0215 Y16.24

N5 G02 X22.0220 Y16.24

Here my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double val5 = 0;
    double val6 = 0;
    bool valid5 = Double.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out val5);        //x axis spacing
    bool valid6 = Double.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out val6);        //Y axis spacing

    double val7;
    double val8;
    bool valid7 = Double.TryParse(textBox7.Text, out val7);        // No of hits in Hits in X -direction
    bool valid8 = Double.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out val8);          // No of hits in Hits in Y -direction
    //// variable from val1 to - - >>> val8

    for (int count = 0; count < val7; count++)
    {
        final_result.WriteLine(("N" + val1++) + ("G0" + val2) + (("X" +val3+count*val5)) + ("Y" + val4));
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Done");
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\user\elec\copy\sample.txt");
}
```

**I want the output like below..**

N1 G02 X22.05 Y16.24

N2 G02 X27.05 Y16.24

N3 G02 X32.05 Y16.24

N4 G02 X37.05 Y16.24

N5 G02 X42.05 Y16.24

Comment: yea.. increment val3

Comment: it should be incremented with the value i am giving in textbox5.. that is val5

Comment: add a sample code with all the variables values like Val1, val2, val3,Val4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a problem with concatenation. Try this:

```
final_result.WriteLine(("N" + val1++) + ("G0" + val2) + (("X" +(val3+count*val5))) + ("Y" + val4));
```

Comment: Glad to hear! The problem is that the compiler was concatenating the "X" with val3 boxed and then concatenating the result of (count * val5). Watch out for string concatenation and adding numbers :P

Comment: Do you know this question.. its also simple.. can u help me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552271/showing-message-box-in-form2-when-i-press-the-cancel-button

Answer (score 0):

Q: What is `val3+count*val5` (at least for the first pass)?

A: That's right.  `val3 + 0`.

SUGGESTION:

Each pass through the loop, set `val3 +=5`.  Or equivalent.  Depending on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: i jsut tried.. i want to increment by value given in textbox5

Comment: OK.  Then set `val3 += val5`.  And make sure val5 is non-zero.

Comment: i gave this ists showing Error The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Comment: Gave like this `("X"+val3+=val5)`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `for loop` **val3** should be:

```
val3+=5;
```

Given that **val3** starts with the value of **0**.

Comment: see it is not always.. that value is depended up the value i am entering in the textbox

Comment: @Stacy You said that you will increment by **5** right? `Val3` is whatever value put it initially or the value from your textbox?